# How to select element which is defined under span from drop down menu

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-select

Hello guys can you help me on this?

Since I cannot select elements from dropdown menu which are in span, from better visual:

[image: here is drop down menu]

Here is html code:

```
<input type="search" autocomplete="none" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_0_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_0_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_0_list_0" readonly="" unselectable="on" value="" style="opacity: 0;" id="rc_select_0" aria-expanded="false">
```

With following solution in selenium I was able to expand dropdown (solution I found here):

```
WebElement dropDown = (WebElement)Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/main/section/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div"));
```

[image: image once dropdown is expanded]

but after that, I tried dozens of the options but I was unable to select any of the elements. For better visual here are spans from all of the items from the drop down:

[image: mr]

```
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Mr.">Mr.</span>
```

[image: mrs]

```
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Mrs.">Mrs.</span>
```

[image: dr]

```
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Dr.">Dr.</span>
```

[image: prof]

```
<span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Prof.">Prof.</span>
```

[image: ms]

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? If so, please add the error message and stack trace to your question. Please include more of the C# code. The visuals are good, but we need to see more of the C# and HTML, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a SELECT element, it's a collection of elements that were created to look like a normal dropdown. You will need to click the top level element to open the dropdown, and then select the desired element once it becomes visible.

Example code to click the "Prof." option under the "Salutation" label:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[.//label[text()='Salutation']//div[@class='ant-select-selection']"))).Click();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[.//label[text()='Salutation']//span[@class='ant-select-selection-item'][@title='Prof.']"))).Click();
```

I'm assuming you are going to use this more than once... you need to set Salutation, First Name, Last Name, etc. I would put this in a method to make it easier to use.

```
/// <summary>
/// Selects an option from the dropdown based on the label and desired option.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="label">The dropdown label.</param>
/// <param name="option">The option to be chosen from the dropdown.</param>
public void SelectOption(string label, string option)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath($"//div[.//label[text()='{label}']//div[@class='ant-select-selection']"))).Click();
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath($"//div[.//label[text()='{label}']//span[@class='ant-select-selection-item'][@title='{option}']"))).Click();
}
```

and then call it like

```
SelectOption("Salutation", "Prof.");
```

Comment: Hello JeffC, Thank you for the help after I changed XPats from your code  I was able to select elements from a drop-down. I have noticed that if we inspect elements from drop down menu by hovering over the element and using a right click that element in the HTML code differs from the elements once is selected on the drop-down menu. So element on hover is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

After a while whit Jeff's help. I was able to select elements from dropdown.Here is a code

/// Driver wait comand

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
```

///Expanding dropdown

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/main/section/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div"))).Click();
```

///Selecting element from dropdown

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div"))).Click();
```